# How to create a reference in loopback?

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

I'm new with loopback and I have some issues with relations.

I have these two models:

course

```
 {
    "name": "course",
    "plural": "courses",
    "base": "PersistedModel",
    "idInjection": false,
    "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
     },
    "properties": {
        "name": {
           "type": "string",
           "required": true
       }
     },
    "validations": [],
    "relations": {
       "toughtBy":{
          "type": "embedsMany",
          "model": "teacher",
          "foreignKey":"",
          "options": {
          "validate": true,
          "forceId": false
       }
    },
    "acls": [],
    "methods": {}
}
```

teacher

```
{
  "name": "teacher",
  "plural": "teachers",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
   "acls": [],
   "methods": []
 }
```

How can I add a existing teacher in an existing course ?

I tried a use the API `put /courses/{id}/toughtBy/{fk}`,  but I get an empty body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confirm but I believe you did not create a course first prior to calling
`POST api/courses/1/thoughtBy/1`, thus you are trying to update a related model instance from a model instance that doesn't exists.

By the way, rather than using `course` `embedsMany` `teacher`, I would recommend you use the following patter:

- `course` `hasAndBelongsToMany` `teacher`

then use

`POST api/courses/` to create a course
`POST api/teachers` to create a teacher
`POST api/courses/link/` with teacherid=1 and courseid=1 to link the both